# Probability disjoint events

Tags: probability

How to prove that P(A ∩ B) + 1 >= P(A) + P(B) isn't P(A ∩ B) = P(A)P(A|B)?
I am not sure how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.
UPD: I made a mistake in the question.  It's P(A ∩ B) + 1 >= P(-A) + P(-B)

Comment: You should also remember that $Pr(A\cup B) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$

Comment: Also, as an aside, $Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A)Pr(B\mid A)$ not $Pr(A)Pr(A\mid B)$

Comment: Thanks, but I made a mistake in my question.

Comment: If by $P(-A)$ you mean the probability of A not happening then what you are trying to prove is not necessarily true. Counterexample: $P(A)=0.01$ and $P(B)=0.01$. Then the left part of the enequality can't be greater than $1.01$ and the right part is $1.98$

Comment: Thanks, I see now